# How To Make CodeIgniter's profiler and ajax requests play nice

Tags: php, codeigniter

from what i can tell, ajax hates when CIs profiler is enabled as it injects html into the `view()` method at the end.Which messes with the `success:` callback on `$.ajax()`.

My thoughts were, rather than defining `$this->output->enable_profiler(false);` on all of my methods that are used for ajax calls, i could use the following code in a hook or core controller that extends CI_Controller.. or somewhere else, just not sure where to put it.

```
<?php
if( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ){
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
}
```

### question:

where can i put the following code, to make CI disable the profiler if its enabled just for ajax requests that would take effect globally across all areas. If there is a better solution of course, let me know. But Google reveals nothing.

Comment: I am also using ajax on my website and didn't get any error if I test after enabling profiler. Could you please explain the error that you get?

Comment: I simply don't use the view method when outputting ajax.

Comment: @Nish i don't get an error, when inspecting the ajax request with dev toolkit i can see the preview tab has the profiler code injected.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets i dont use the view method either on ajax methods. but the profiler will still run even without the `view()`.

Comment: Got it. With AJAX response you will get the profiler display also. So if you are displaying or parsing the response it will be problem. In my case I was using the response text to detect if the update is success or failure. So I didn't get these errors.

Comment: Yeah, and in my case im echoing a `json_encoded` array for the response.. So i need a way to check if the request is ajax and if it is then dont show the profiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please extend the core controller and in the constructor check for an special post variable name in the post array and disable the profiler.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(isset($_POST['is_ajax_request'])
            $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
    }
}
```

When sending ajax request send a field is_ajax_request to disable profiler.

Comment: CI has `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` wouldn't this work instead of passing a hidden field?

Comment: I am not sure in all the browsers the header HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is set for ajax request in all the browsers. If it is so that is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered, but I used this instead of passing a field in MY_Controller.php

```
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
    } else {
        $this->output->enable_profiler(true);
    }
```

Tested in Chrome and only needed on my dev box anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply instead of

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

do a

```
die(json_encode($json));
```

? Leaves the system no chance to print out profiler.